# Why mysql complains the Select List contains nonaggregated column when outer joining a subquery on nullable column?

Tags: mysql, group-by

When I run the following sql, mysql (version 5.7) complains

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'count_cabinet.cabinet_count' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `bundle_v2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `cabinet_v2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bundle_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The sql:

```
SELECT bundle_v2.id AS bundle_id,
 count_cabinet.cabinet_count AS count_cabinet_cabinet_count
FROM bundle_v2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT cabinet_v2.bundle_id AS bundle_id, count(cabinet_v2.id) AS cabinet_count 
    FROM cabinet_v2
    GROUP BY cabinet_v2.bundle_id
) AS count_cabinet ON count_cabinet.bundle_id = bundle_v2.id
GROUP BY bundle_v2.id
```

If we set `cabinet_v2.bundle_id` to be `NOT NUL` or change `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `JOIN`, everything works fine. But unfortunately we can't do that.

I know the new rule for mysql about `group_by`, that the columns in the select list should be unique for the value in `group_by`. But I can't figure out a case when the `cabinet_count` is not unique with respect to `bundle_v2.id`. Can someone kindly shed a light on that?

BTW: This sql is part of a big sql, and we have to use subquery here. So removing subquery doesn't work for us.

Fiddler: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJqgLnU6NtPrRBUWQNqr8L/0

Comment: I think the last GROUP BY bundle_v2.id is not needed over here, since you already used GROUP BY in inner query, which will give you one row per 'bundle_id'. otherwise you need to add aggregate function on 'count_cabinet.cabinet_count' as the error suggested.

Comment: @Yeou  As I said, the sql shown here is just a small part of a huge sql. and we can't remove `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id`

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id` in the outer query is meaningless here and it's not an issue of nullable column.

The inner query will return one row for every `bundle_id` as it is grouping it together and giving you `cabinet_v2.id` count.

So you can run the query without `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id`

```
SELECT bundle_v2.id AS bundle_id,
 count_cabinet.cabinet_count AS count_cabinet_cabinet_count
FROM bundle_v2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT cabinet_v2.bundle_id AS bundle_id, count(cabinet_v2.id) AS cabinet_count 
    FROM cabinet_v2
    GROUP BY cabinet_v2.bundle_id
) AS count_cabinet ON count_cabinet.bundle_id = bundle_v2.id
```

For any reason, if you can't remove the `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id` from the query, you can use `max` function on `count_cabinet.cabinet_count`

```
SELECT bundle_v2.id AS bundle_id,
 MAX(count_cabinet.cabinet_count) AS count_cabinet_cabinet_count
FROM bundle_v2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT cabinet_v2.bundle_id AS bundle_id, count(cabinet_v2.id) AS cabinet_count 
    FROM cabinet_v2
    GROUP BY cabinet_v2.bundle_id
) AS count_cabinet ON count_cabinet.bundle_id = bundle_v2.id
GROUP BY bundle_v2.id
```

**Edit**

> Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'count_cabinet.cabinet_count' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The error clearly states that you have not used any aggregate function on column `count_cabinet.cabinet_count`, since it is not in the `group by` list.

Here you can do a few things depending on your requirement:-

1. Use a aggregate function on `count_cabinet.cabinet_count`.
2. Use it with the `group by` clause, like this `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id, count_cabinet.cabinet_count`
3. You utilize the MySQL extended feature for the `group by` like this `SET sql_mode = '';` and then running your query.

**Note:** Step 3 can give you unexpected results.

These are not a workaround. These are hard and fast rules of the `group by`. You need to follow it, or you'll face the error that you have already experienced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I said, the sql shown here is just a small part of a huge sql. and we can't remove `GROUP BY bundle_v2.id`. And yes, I can use `MAX` (or better `ANY_VALUE`).  But I just want to know why the original sql doesn't work.

Comment: As I said, you need to use an aggregate function on a column that is not included in the `group by` clause. That's how `group by` works, either you add that column to `group by` or use an aggregate function.

Comment: That's not true. Mysql will check the uniqueness (with respect to group_by columns) for columns in Select List. Here i am pretty sure that for each bundle_id, there is only exact one cabinet_count. Mysql should be able to find it and pass the uniqueness check. But for the reason I don't know, the check fails.

Comment: Go through this link again for basic rules. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: if you want to ignore the rules run `SET sql_mode = '';` this may have unexpected result.

Comment: Thank you for you kind help. I know how to work around this error, but I still want to want to know why I *need* to work around.

Comment: you really need to read the `group by` document again. It's necessary to use an aggregate function on columns that is on `select` list, but not in `group by`. ex `select col1, col2 from table1 group by col1` this will give same error that you are facing. you must use a aggregate function on `col2` or use that column on `group by` like this `select col1, col2 from table1 group by col1, col2`.